# Create Layout Programmatically in android - issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I am creating FrameLayout dynamically using the following code

mylayout.java

```
FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);            
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

webview=new WebView(this);
webview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

splashview=new ImageView(this);
splashview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
splashview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
splashview.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash);
splashview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

progressbar=new ProgressBar(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
progressbar.setLayoutParams(params);
progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);          


layout.addView(webview);
layout.addView(progressbar);
layout.addView(splashview);

setContentView(layout);
```

**mylayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </WebView>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible" />




    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/myimg"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I need the `equalent code for the above xml file in java`. what mistake i did?

Note: Using the above java code, each one is overlapping.

Comment: what mistake i did? -- what mistake did you notice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Android Developer - Frame Layout Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) reads:

*Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the `android:layout_gravity` attribute.*

In your case, you may use `layout.setForegroundGravity(int)` for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

or

```
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

You forgot to set the gravity of the layout.

Comment: if i use the above code for Framwork layout, showing an error as "undefined method"

Comment: Yes, you are right.... but the method is setForgroundGravity. Anyway Thank you. Giving upvote