# Listview in Relative layout

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android

I'm probably missing something simple here, but I just can't see it...

So, I have a vanilla ListView a custom adapter and a relative layout.
Currently, items in the listview don't show. However, the custom adapter works, as long as the listview is not in a relative layout (ex: frame layout). On the other side, I can have the listview in a relative layout... as long as I don't use my custom adapter.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            ListView list = new ListView (this);
            list.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Red);

            RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout (this);
            rl.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);

            TextView tv = new TextView (this);
            tv.Text = "Some text";
            tv.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
            rl.AddView (tv, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (400, 100));

            List<RelativeLayout> views = new List<RelativeLayout>();
            views.Add (rl);

            testAdapter adapter = new testAdapter (views, this);

            //ArrayAdapter<string> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);
            //arrayAdapter.Add ("cell 1");

            list.Adapter = adapter;

            RelativeLayout listContainer = new RelativeLayout (this);
            listContainer.AddView (list, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (400, 600));
            listContainer.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray);

            this.AddContentView (listContainer, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
        }
    }

    class testAdapter:BaseAdapter{

        List<RelativeLayout> views = new List<RelativeLayout>();
        Android.Content.Context context;

        public testAdapter(List<RelativeLayout> inView, Android.Content.Context cntx){
            views = inView;
            context = cntx;
        }

        #region implemented abstract members of BaseAdapter
        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem (int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override long GetItemId (int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            RelativeLayout temp;
            if (convertView != null) {
                temp = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
                temp.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
            } else {
                temp = new RelativeLayout (context);
            }
            temp.RemoveAllViews ();

            if (position < views.Count) {
                RelativeLayout refView = views [position];
                View refParent = (View)refView.Parent;
                if (refParent != null)
                    ((ViewGroup)refParent).RemoveView (refView);
                temp.AddView (refView);
                temp.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
            }

            return (View)temp;
        }
        public override int Count {
            get {
                return views.Count;
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

At this point, I only need to change `listContainer` from a RelativeLayout to a FrameLayout and everything is well. Or I could keep the relative layout and change the `adapter` to the `arrayAdapter` that I commented out. I know this is doable but I'm not using any `wrap content` that usually causes these kind of issues.

Something else: The cell returned by the getView never gets any dimensions. However, if I were to force some dimensions (ex: by adding below `temp.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Green);` something like `temp.LayoutParameters = new AbsListView(300, 100);`) the green cell will actually appear, but not its content.

Comment: I'm using a custom ArrayAdapter , a RelativeLayout containing a ListView and also the view that is used for each row of list is in a RelativeLayout and everything works fine. What does `temp.RemoveAllViews();` do inside the adapter? What is its use?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but for a lack of reputation i can't comment, only reply.
Maybe it's not the solution you were looking for but it might work: have you tryed leaving the list in a FrameLayout and placing the FrameLayout in a RelativeLayout?

Comment: obiouvsly if it's not working/it's not the solution u were looking for i will delete the answer :)

Comment: It works as a just-make-it-work solution. It's already something I was considering using if I can't find an answer but this is part of a bigger project and I have narrowed down an issue I have with a listView to this weird thing. Ideally, I would prefer a concise solution to the relative layout, but eventually I will settle for whatever works :P

Comment: I was thinking, what about trying to do the same thing by xml side? You are creating the view by code programmatically, maybe doing same thing but from visual could word.

add try have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896817/create-layout-programmatically-in-android-issue
might solve your problem!